# How do I get phpThumb to recognize and use ImageMagick installation?

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick, phpthumb

I have phpThumb and ImageMagick installed on my server. The phpThumb configuration analyzer shows green for most items, but it says "ImageMagick not found" in orange.

I am pretty sure that ImageMagick is installed and working, as the imagick section appears in my phpinfo(), and I can run the below test script successfully:

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "magick:rose");
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->roundCorners(5,3);
$type=$im->getFormat();
header("Content-type: $type");
echo $im->getimageblob();
?>
```

However, I can't figure out how to get phpThumb to recognize and use the ImageMagick installation. Any thoughts on why phpThumb might not be seeing ImageMagick?

phpThumb version is 1.7.15

ImageMagick version is ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently in the same boat with "ImageMagick 6.9.9-28 Q16 amd64 2018-01-02 http://www.imagemagick.org" with "Image Magick Module version 3.4.3" and using "phpThumb 1.7.15-201802181529".
I can also run the script you provided to create an image with imagemagick to show that it works.

I decided to ask the creator of phpThumb, and turns out the php extension of ImageMagick is currently not supported, only the commandline version is.

Here's my discussion with the creator on his github about this issue:
https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/phpThumb/issues/110